# I don't get the output i should get when using a if-statement with header file. [C-Programming]

Tags: c

```
void test(char text[], char testCipher[], int *längd, int *nyckel)

{

 int i = 0;
 int j = 0;

  while(text[i] != '\0')
  {
   i++;
  }

 *längd = i - 1;

  while(text[j] != '\0')
  {
   if(text[j] >= 'a' && text[j] <= 'z')
   {
     testCipher[j] = text[j] + 3;
     j++;
     *nyckel = *nyckel + 1;
   }
  }
 }



int main()
{

 char plainText[100];
 char cipherText[100];
 int length, key;


  printf("Enter a text you want to encrypt: ");
  fgets(plainText, 99, stdin);

  test(plainText, cipherText, &length, &key);
  printf("%d\n%s\n%d", length, cipherText, key);

 return 0;
}
```

## Terminal output

Enter a text you want to encrypt: ->After this nothing happens i can just input unlimited letters<-

Since i added the if-statement this started happening before that it worked.

Comment: Please properly format the code you show. Also please remove anything that's not inside your real code. As it stands it's a mess, sry.

Comment: There's no header file (#include) I can see. The subject line is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You pass address of `length` and `key` to function which are *unintialized* .  And then in function you do this -

```
 *nyckel = *nyckel + 1;
```

`*nyckel` the address holds no value and you are trying to read it(*basically I don't see use of this variable (??)*) . Initialize both the variables before passing them to function or in function .

Comment: I intialized them still the same problem. Everything works until i use the if-statement. So basically before i used the if statement i could give a input to my variable plainText and get the right output. So if i wrote a i would get the output d but when i added the if-statement it stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

Consider what happens when your text contains a character that is *not* a letter -- the `if` means that you don't do anything with that character, and don't go on to the next character (don't increment `j`), so you just loop over the same character again...